# Embed python within bokeh JavaScript callback code

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, bokeh

Is it possible to embed python code inside bokeh JavaScript code within a callback?

For example I would like [the following snippet](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#id22) to plot a linear regression straight line instead of the simple mean horizontal line by using python `scipy.stats.linregress` and not JavaScript Math or directly computing in JavaScript.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Link to the snippet is broken.